# Command needed by dialogue box generated after clicking on “Ubuntu” Tile on Windows 10 Startup Menu

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, execute-command, prompt

I desperately need to know what response is being sought by a DOS-type dialogue box that appears every time I click on the “Ubuntu” tile on my “Windows 10 Startup Menu”.  I had previously asked if anyone knew how I could install “Ubuntu 18.04” on the SSD, or the HDD of my new, high-spec, “Metabox” laptop, alongside the “Windows 10” O.S. that had been installed on the SSD by the manufacturers.  I attempted to install Ubuntu to Dual Boot with Windows 10.  I was eventually able to get my similarly spec’d Desktop PC to accept Ubuntu 18.04 but not my Laptop.

As I was unable to get my question answered by any of the many sources I asked, including “Ask Ubuntu”, after weeks of serious frustration I relented and went for what I thought might be the next-best thing to a Dual Boot installation, obtaining my copy of Ubuntu 18.04 from the Microsoft Store and installing it to run within the Windows 10 O.S.

This appeared as though it was going to work but every time I click on the “Ubuntu” tile on the Windows 10 Start Menu it present a dialogue box with a Command Prompt.  Regardless of my response, the Command Prompt returns advising “command not found” and on the following line, “metame2@Metabox-Laptop:~$”, with the cursor blinking away, awaiting another attempt at the needed command.

”metame2” is the username I adopted and “Metabox-Laptop” the name I gave the new laptop.  I have no idea what command is required here.  Does anyone else have any clue, please.

Comment: You actually are at a Bash prompt in your Ubuntu installation... What else did you expect to happen? (The Ubuntu installed in the Windows Subsystem for Linux is the server edition. If you want to run the desktop edition then my suggestion is to run it in a virtual machine using VMware Player or VirtualBox.)

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I have looked into the Virtual Machine method of Ubuntu 18.04 installation but the more I read the more technical and out of my league it appeared to be.  Also, having not heard of using "Virtual Machines" I was not aware of their pros and cons, in order to take the punt on using one.